# How to handle exception in findAny().get()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type, nosuchelementexception

In the below code if queueName is changed to `TEST` (or any name not in map), then getting the exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` at line `.get();`

Code is working for values in the map .

Requesting for suggestions as to how to handle this case efficiently for `queueName` not in map.

```
public class Optional3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> headers = 
                new HashMap<String, String>();

        headers.put("JMS_REPLY_TO_QUEUE", "reply");
        headers.put("ERROR_QUEUE", "error");
        headers.put("RETRY_QUEUE", "retry");
        headers.put("OK_QUEUE", "ok");

        String queueName = "JMS_REPLY_TO_QUEUE"; //working
        //String queueName = "TEST"; //not working

        Optional<String> jmsReplToQueueNameOp = headers.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(header -> header.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(queueName))
                .map(jmsReplToQueue -> jmsReplToQueue.getValue())
                .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                .findAny()
                .get();

        String jmsReplToQueueName = jmsReplToQueueNameOp.isPresent() ? 
                                    jmsReplToQueueNameOp.get() : 
                                    "default";

        System.out.println(jmsReplToQueueName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just delete `.map(Optional::ofNullable)` and `.get()` from your pipeline... Your second last statement also doesn't need to be more complex than `String jmsReplToQueueName = jmsReplToQueueNameOp.orElse("default");`

Comment: Replace `.map(Optional::ofNullable)` with `.filter(e -> e != null)`. This should solve it.

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k, the solution worked

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) API. It is used to get the value mapped with the specified key. If no value is mapped with the provided key then the default value is returned like this:

```
String jmsReplToQueueName = headers.getOrDefault("TEST", "default");
```